# faceting by unique pairs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create some plots with ggplot using faceting. I'm relatively new to ggplot so I'm struggeling setting up the plot. For testing I set up some test data. The actual data is huge and I want first to play around with these toy case. Here is the toy data

```
m1 <- matrix(rep(c("Skin","Human"),100),ncol = 2,byrow = T)
m2 <- matrix(rep(c("Head","Animal"),200),ncol = 2, byrow=T)
m3 <- matrix(rep(c("Skin","Animal"),250), ncol = 2, byrow=T)
y <- rnorm(550,0,1)
x1 <- rnorm(100,0,1)
x2 <- rnorm(200,0,1)
x3 <- rnorm(250,0,1)

m1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(x1,m1))
m2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(x2,m2))
m3 <- as.data.frame(cbind(x3,m3))
colnames(m1) <- c("x1","type","class")
colnames(m2) <- c("x1","type","class")
colnames(m3) <- c("x1","type","class")
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(y,rbind(m1,m2,m3)))
data <- cbind(data,rnorm(550,0,1))
colnames(data) <- c("y","x1","type","class","x2")
data <- data[,c("y","x1","x2","type","class")]

plot(sort(data[1:100,"y"]),sort(data[1:100,"x1"]),col="red")
points(sort(data[1:100,"y"]),sort(data[1:100,"x2"]),col="blue")
```

I would like to have a plot for all unique pairs of `c("type","class")` where in each plot I see two scatterplots of `x1` and `x2` against `y`. I thought facetting is the right approach, however I'm struggeling to achieve the desired result.

Comment: what do you mean "..in each plot" you "see two scatterplots"? I dont know what it means to see two plots in a plot...please be more clear (or specific) or provide an example of your desired output.

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian there is an example of a plot at the end. I would like to have such a plot for each unique pair

Comment: so is that three types? Skin-Animal, Skin-human, Head-Animal?

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian exactly in this case there should be three plots, each showing two drawings. One of y against x1 and another of y against x2.

Comment: in the comments you're saying you want to facet_wrap by type and class but theres only one type and class in the data in the example you provided...``data[1:100]`` grabs the top 100 rows, thus only including "Skin" and "Human"...

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian I just showed a plot for one pair `c("skin", "human")`. I can add the other two as well. The point is using normal plot I have to do this manually. With ggplot I could automatically create these three plots using facetting. If wanted I can add the other plots for the other two pairs as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the plots that your sample code generates, it seems like you want to plot two sets of points `(x1,y)` and `(x2,y)` on the same plot, which `ggplot` is able to handle well. However, `ggplot` works well with *long* tables rather than *wide* ones.

I've provided one way to achieve your desired outcome. The following steps can be performed after your chunk of code to achieve the desired outcome.

1. Melt your table wide-to-long make use of `ggplot`'s in-built functionality. Note that the `color` argument automatically plots the `x1` and `x2` in different colors.

   ```
   library(reshape2) # Used to melt the table 
   library(ggplot2) # Used to plot
   data <- melt(data, id.vars = c('type','class','y'), measure.vars = c('x1','x2'))
   head(data)
     # type class          y variable              value
   # 1 Skin Human  1.3170057       x1  -1.09101346133313
   # 2 Skin Human  1.2805021       x1 -0.883308758331181
   # 3 Skin Human -0.7620298       x1 0.0800447346341697
   # 4 Skin Human  0.2766297       x1  0.589741587886533
   # 5 Skin Human -1.8504755       x1 -0.178520217862402
   # 6 Skin Human  0.6474738       x1    0.1039386636512

   p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = as.numeric(value), y = y, color = variable))
   print(p1)
   ```

   [image: un-faceted plot]
2. Using `facet_wrap` to facet by unique combinations of `type` and `class`

   ```
   faceted <- p1 + facet_wrap(~type + class)
   print(faceted)
   ```

[image: output plot]

Comment: many for the anwser. One last question regarding 2. How can I tune the desired structure. In your second plot we have essential a matrix with one row and three columns. In the real data I have approximately 30 unique pairs.

Comment: @math Look at the documentation for `facet_wrap`, but essentially it takes arguments `nrow` and `ncol` to adjust the output accordingly